# Unity vs custom dependency injection?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to justify using Unity for dependency injection vs a custom interface such as:

```
public interface IResolver
{
   ITypeA TypeA { get; }
   ITypeB TypeB { get; }
}

public static ResolverFactory
{
   // set by unit tests or Main() method, etc.
   public static IResolver DefaultResolver { get; set; }
}
```

Why would one choose to go with a more complicated approach like the Unity framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DI by its nature is complex. Applying DI in a simple scenario as is often done in tutorials and examples would at first glance always seem like overkill. DI only starts to pay dividends when the *application* is complex.

When you have a complex application, then adding DI to compose the application makes sense. Using convention-based configuration (which most DI containers support out of the box) can save hundreds or thousands of lines of configuration code and make the application much simpler to maintain. Your simple DI container has no convention-based configuration.

Writing your own DI container is not reinventing the wheel. A wheel is very simple, DI is complex. Writing your own DI container is more like reinventing the light bulb. Why go through the trouble when you can get one that is fully featured (for free, in fact) and screw it into place?

Besides, you have completely missed the point. What you have invented is a [service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). A DI container is not normally used in that way. Most DI containers have a built-in ability to *automatically* recursively inject dependencies into the constructors of entire object graphs. They are typically used for [*application composition*](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), not service location. This is their main purpose.

For your simple DI container to work that way, you will need to load each type using Reflection, analyze the constructors and come up with some standardized way to choose the best one, then load all of the dependency types (the constructor parameters), and their dependencies, etc. recursively. Then you would have to start at the bottom of the object graph and recursively call the best constructor of each type using Reflection to create an instance of each type. Recursively creating the dependencies of each instance before creating the instance itself until the entire object graph is composed. You would probably also eventually need to reinvent a way to do property injection. All of this work can be avoided by simply downloading a NuGet package and reading the documentation for an existing DI container.

I strongly recommend you read the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/). DI is one of the most misunderstood concepts in software development, and it is well worth the investment of studying the topic in detail on its own without having to sift through the misinformation on the Internet. There are many benefits to be gained by proper use of DI, but improper usage is often worse than not using DI at all. Not to mention, the book gives you *loads* of additional reasons why the world doesn't need yet another DI container implementation.

Oh, and one last thing - don't use Unity. Unity is one of the worst DI containers that is lacking several important features. On the other hand, Autofac, Ninject, StructureMap, and Castle Windsor are all good choices.

Comment: I strongly agree with the book recommendation.  Its something any developer should read......

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to implement your own DI implementation, I would suggest that you first look into ones like Unity, Autofac, StructureMap, or Ninject.

Why?  Simply put: don't reinvent the wheel.  DI libraries have been written and are pretty flexible.  They have various hooks for ASP.NET MVC as well.  Writing your own is doing more work when you could utilize an existing library.  If you really need your own implementation, go for it, but I'll reckon that one of the many DI libraries out there will fill your need.

Comment: I'm all for not reinventing the wheel.  My confusion is that frameworks like Unity seem like overkill.  The code that needs to be written for DI is simple, using a framework actually causes more code and complexity IMO.